# How do I center an inline-block element of variable width?

Tags: html, css

I have an inline-block `nav` element that needs to be centered inside its parent container. But because the width is `auto` (because I need it to shrink to its content), I can't center it.

And I can't use `text-align: center` because I don't want the text content to be centered. I just want the `mainNavigation` element to be centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/vpvzmg3j/3/

How can I center this thing?

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

#mainNavigation
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

    #mainNavigation div
    {
        width: auto;
        float: left;
    }

        #mainNavigation div p
        {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #mainNavigation div ul
        {
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            float: left;
        }

            #mainNavigation div ul li
            {
                list-style-type: none;
                display: inline;
            }
```

```html
<nav id="mainNavigation">
    <div id="homeMenuContainer">
        <p class="noDisplay">Home</p>
        <ul id="homeMenu">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="helpAndSupportMenuContainer">
        <p>Help &amp; Support</p>
        <ul id="helpAndSupportMenu">
            <li><a href="">User Guides</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Video Tutorials</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="myAccountMenuContainer">
        <p>My Account</p>
        <ul id="myAccountMenu">
            <li><a href="">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Quickfix is display: table;

Comment: @Kristine Thank you. I actually just found a solution, after spending quite a while on it. I'll post mine too for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vpvzmg3j/11/) what you are looking for?

The code updates :

```
#mainNavigation {
    text-align: center; /*this does the trick with its child*/
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

    #mainNavigation div {
        /*you said you want them on the left side*/
        text-align: left;
        background-color: blue;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-left: -4px; /*inline-block space remove*/

    }
```

Comment: That is exactly the solution I just came up with. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vpvzmg3j/9/

add blow changes, that will center align the nav and same time left align the content:

```
    #mainNavigation{text-align: left;}
    .center-div{text-align:center;}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="center-div"> <nav id="mainNavigation"> .....</nav> </div>
```